# Destroy random item LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm making a brickbreaker game and there's an explosion item that needs to cause one random brick to explode

```
for (BaseActor brock : BaseActor.getList("Brick"))
{
    //Item it = new Item(0,0,mainStage);
    //it.alignToActorCenter(brock);   
    brock.remove();
    score += 100; //Adds 100 to score
    scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score); //Displays new score
    break;
}
```

This destroys the first break only, if I didn't use "break;" it destroys all of the bricks, is there anyway I can select a brick at random and have that destroyed instead of the first brick specifically being destroyed? Or is there a function that returns a specific brick from the list so that I can generate a number with math random and then destroy the brick at that number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's little confusion or may be logical error, `BaseActor` having a list of same type (`BaseActor`).

You can get a random brick from list and remove in this way :

```
private void destroyOneRandomBrick(){

    ArrayList<BaseActor> brickList = BaseActor.getList("Brick");
    int randomBrickIndex= MathUtils.random(brickList.size()-1);
    BaseActor randomBrick= brickList.get(randomBrickIndex);
    randomBrick.remove();   //Actor removed from stage
    s.remove(randomBrick);  //Item removed from ArrayList
    score+=100;
    scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + score);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think,you need not to use for each loop

> BaseActor.getList("Brick")

gives you the list,you can pick any random value of that list.
  Make object of
   Random random =Random();
      BaseActor actorToRemove=BaseActor.getList("Brick").get(random.nextInt(yourList.size()));
actorToRemove.remove();

Comment: BaseActor.getList("Brick")   is it return ArrayList ?

Answer (score 1):

If you have `BaseActor` use libGDX's `Array` class instead of Java's list, you can use its `random()` method to easily seek and remove a random brick like so:

```
BaseActor.getList().remove( BaseActor.getList().random() );
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

`BaseActor.getList(mainStage ,"Brick");`

`brick.remove();`